# How do I get the position of a control relative to the window's client rect?

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi

I want to be able to write code like this:

```
HWND hwnd = <the hwnd of a button in a window>;
int positionX;
int positionY;
GetWindowPos(hwnd, &positionX, &positionY);
SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, positionX, positionY, 0, 0, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE);
```

And have it do nothing. However, I can't work out how to write a `GetWindowPos()` function that gives me answers in the correct units:

```
void GetWindowPos(HWND hWnd, int *x, int *y)
{
    HWND hWndParent = GetParent(hWnd);

    RECT parentScreenRect;
    RECT itemScreenRect;
    GetWindowRect(hWndParent, &parentScreenRect);
    GetWindowRect(hWnd, &itemScreenRect);

    (*x) = itemScreenRect.left - parentScreenRect.left;
    (*y) = itemScreenRect.top - parentScreenRect.top;
}
```

If I use this function, I get coordinates that are relative to the top-left of the parent window, but `SetWindowPos()` wants coordinates relative to the area below the title bar (I'm presuming this is the "client area", but the win32 terminology is all a bit new to me).

**Solution**
This is the working `GetWindowPos()` function (thanks Sergius):

```
void GetWindowPos(HWND hWnd, int *x, int *y)
{
    HWND hWndParent = GetParent(hWnd);
    POINT p = {0};

    MapWindowPoints(hWnd, hWndParent, &p, 1);

    (*x) = p.x;
    (*y) = p.y;
}
```

Comment: How does it work, What is the use of DirectX. Newbie in directx. I made my own function to do this

Comment: Yes it is a windows application, hence the use of win32 api.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try to use `GetClientRect` to get coordinates and `MapWindowPoints` to transform it.

Answer (score 1):

I think u want something like that. I don't know hot to find controls. 
This segment of code alligns position of a label in the center of window form according to the size of form.

```
AllignLabelToCenter(lblCompanyName, frmObj)


 Public Sub AllignLabelToCenter(ByRef lbl As Label, ByVal objFrm As Form)
        Dim CenterOfForm As Short = GetCenter(objFrm.Size.Width)
        Dim CenterOfLabel As Short = GetCenter(lbl.Size.Width)
        lbl.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(CenterOfForm - CenterOfLabel, lbl.Location.Y)
    End Sub
    Private ReadOnly Property GetCenter(ByVal obj As Short)
        Get
            Return obj / 2
        End Get
    End Property
```

Comment: That isn't really useful as there isn't an equivalent to the ".Location" property you are using in the win32 (or at least, none that I've found).

Comment: i never used win32. In case u get a solution, plz let me know it too